# column type automatically converting into boolean using case statement in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to replace all '1' by yes and '0' by no. The query I have written is:

```
second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire.is_there_a_sill_band = case
   when second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire.is_there_a_sill_band = '1' then 'YES'
   when second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire.is_there_a_sill_band = '0' then 'NO'
   end as is_there_a_sill_band,
```

where 'second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire' is my table name and 'is_there_a_sill_band' is my column name of type 'text'.There is not any error. But the problem is using this it converts the column type as boolean and the result I get is 'f' whether it is '0' or '1'. Please help. I am using postgresql 9.4 and pg admin III.

Comment: Where's the rest of your update statement?

Comment: Rest part mean- "select " and "from" ? It's a huge statement which is working perfectly. So I didnt mention. The problem is only in this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the result of a comparison between the current value of `is_there_still_a_band` and the new value, which will always be false.

The select should look like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN is_there_a_sill_band = '1' THEN 'YES'
    WHEN is_there_a_sill_band = '0' THEN 'NO'
  END AS is_there_a_sill_band
FROM second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire;
```

Your select is equivalent to the above, but with an extraneous comparison that always evaluates to `false`:

```
SELECT
  is_there_a_sill_band =
  CASE
    WHEN is_there_a_sill_band = '1' THEN 'YES'
    WHEN is_there_a_sill_band = '0' THEN 'NO'
  END AS is_there_a_sill_band
FROM second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire;
```

For example, if the current value is `1`, the case statement evaluates to `YES`. You're selecting `'1' = 'YES' AS is_there_a_sill_band`. `'1' = 'YES'` is a boolean statement that evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I did not understand what you are pointing? are you talking about '=' that is before case as 'second_tranche_inspection_reporting_questionnaire.is_there_a_sill_band = case'? and update query means? Do I actually need to update the data before using select statement? If so, that's not my aim. I need to have the data as yes for 1 to display using the query without actually updating the data in database.